# Manage update from an apk programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, google-glass, google-gdk

I try to update an App on Google Glass programmatically but ended everytime in following error message:

```
Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.bp2go.glassapkupdater/files/Pictures/apks/app-release.apk
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

My provider_paths.xml:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="apks" path="Android/data/com.bp2go.glassapkupdater/Pictures/apks"/>
```

and my method to call the apk:

```
var path_apk = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()+"/apks/"
val fileName = "app-release.apk"
val path_to_apk = path_apk+fileName

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)
intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.bp2go.glassapkupdater.fileprovider", File(path_to_apk)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
startActivity(intent)
```

but when I use this lines:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(outputFile),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
startActivity(intent)
```

I got following error on start:

```
"There was a problem parsing the package".
```

.apk is in internal storage in Pictures/apks/, doesn't have a external storage on google glass. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `getUriForFile()` returns the Uri for a file under your app's data directory, hence why it asks for a package name. Just use `Uri.parse(path_to_apk);`

Comment: Then I get following error:

   **No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.bp2go.glassapkupdater/files/Pictures/apks/app-release.apk flg=0x1 }**